# TestComplete: Why does my Javascript code only works when there is a breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, wpf, click, testcomplete

I'm trying to simulate a click on a checkbox via Test Complete but it seems to work only if I use a breakpoint and follow it step by step. If I run this function, it won't work. Here's my code:

```
 function Click_on_Checkbox(new_value){
  var checkbox;
  checkbox = rootNode.Find("WPFControlName","allowChangePar",50);
  if(checkbox.IsChecked==true){
    checkbox.Click();
  } 
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide details. What do you mean when telling that the script does not work? Have you tried to check the **checkbox** object for existence? Have you tried to insert a delay before searching for the object?

Comment: @DmitryNikolaev I've tried to check the checkbox for existence and inserted a delay of 1 second. I figured that the object was already found but the program could not perform a Click on it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by typing `checkbox.Focus();` before `checkbox.Click();`